# Meaning of "drones save on productivity for our maintenance personnel"

Tags: phrase-meaning

[From an article](https://ohsonline.com/Articles/2019/08/12/Companies-Use-Drones-to-Limit-Dangerous-Potentially-Fatal-Tasks-for-Workers.aspx?m=1&Page=2):

> “Drones save us downtime, save cost, **save on productivity for our maintenance personnel**,” Bardin said. “They eliminate having to put a person in that potentially hazardous environment.”

It's hard to understand the meaning of the phrase in bold. Does it mean "the drones save the money that would have been spent on paying to the maintenance personnel"?

But there's the word "productivity" that usually means the efficacy of work. The whole phase feels hazy.

Drones improve the overall maintenance productivity and the overall maintenance costs go down?

Comment: It looks like Bardin had two conflicting ideas about how to form that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... save on productivity for our maintenance personnel ...

The phrase here means the drone **boosts** productivity for their personnel, or **save them work time and effort**.